# Rank of matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

i need a little help with an exercise on my class. We have to do this exercise [image: http://eclass.uoa.gr/courses/mathimg/math_941.5_20c3a240fc1c7add2340353330e539d2.png]

for a = 2, b = 4, c = 0

How can i determine λ if a know that the rank of the matrix is 2 ?

Comment: also please indicate symbols correctly,i can't see $c$ in your determinant

Comment: Find the determinant and see for which $\lambda$ it is 0 (there are at most four such values for $\lambda$). Then put those values in the matrix and see when you get a matrix whose rank is 2 (by using Gauss row operations); or use row reduction since the beginning

Answer (score 0):

if rank of matrix is $2$,it means for  matrices for sizes more then  $2$,all minor determinants and also  whole determinant is just zero,so you need to compute determinants seperately with size more then   $2$ and set to zero,also dont forget there must be  at least one matrix with size  $2$ by $2$ with non zero determinant

Comment: my matrix is

{{3+l,  6,  3,  l+3},{6, 7,  3,  7},{3,    3,  7,  6},{l+3,  7,  6,  11}}

can you help me with that. So i can understand how i have to resolve exerises like this ?